# React component to handle data only (none rendering component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm wondering if it's acceptable approach to use react for handling data components (methods) or how it should be called.

Here is an example to describe what I mean:

Example data object which should be fetched from api:

```js
  import React from 'react';
```

```js
  // Example of api response.
  data = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    value: 'baz',
  }
```

```js
  // src/components/api/useApiHook.js
  
  const useApiHook = () => {
  
    const [response, setResponse] = React.useState({});
  
    const fetchData = (request) =>
      axios
        .post('https://url.com/api/data', { ...request })
        .then(({ data }) => setResponse({ ...data }));
  
    return { fetchData, response };
  };
```

> Probably `exampleData` should have capitalized name.

```js
  // src/components/Example/exampleData.js

  const exampleData = () => {
  
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  
    const { fetchData, response } = useApiHook();
    
    // should I use react like this, I mean in the non-jsx component
    React.useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, []);
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (response) {
       return setData(response)
      }
    }, [response]);
  
    //
    // After response received and before return it
    // we can provide some manipulations, or so.
    //
  
    return data;
  };
```

> Main component which should render the data.
> And whenever `exampleData` `->` `data` will get some update, we will be able render this new data.

```js
  // src/components/Example/Example.js

  const Example = () => {
  
    const data = exampleDataComponent();
  
    return (<>
      <p>id: {data.id }</p>
      <p>name: {data.name }</p>
      <p>value: {data.value }</p>
    </>);
  };
```

---

The reason for this kind of structure is to divide the rendering and data manipulation/aggregation. I omitted validation, verification in examples. Generally, everything what I want to do is some kind of middle service (`exampleData`) between api hook and jsx.

**My question**: does approach like this can be used in real life? the code works fine, but I think you got the point.

Thank you.

**working code snippet attached**

```js
// Get a hook function
// import React from 'react'
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
// const {useState, useEffect, createElement} = React;
// const {render} = ReactDOM;

/**
 * API HOOK
 */
const useApiHook = () => {

  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState({});

  // axios.post('url/api/data', { ...data }).then(({ res }) => setResponse({ ...res }));
  const fetchData = () => setResponse(() => {
    console.log('[step-3] useApiHook | fetching data @fetchData');
    return {
      id:       1,
      name:     'Sam',
      position: 'Driver'
    };
  });

  console.log('@useApiHook | return { fetchData, response } | Current response', response);
  return {
    fetchData,
    response
  };
};

/**
 * Data manipulator/aggregator.
 */
const exampleData = () => {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  const { fetchData, response } = useApiHook();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[step-2] useEffect | calling fetchData from: exampleData');
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[step-4] useEffect called');

    if(response) {
      console.log('[step-4] setData(response)', response);
      return setData(response);
    }
  }, [response]);

  //
  // After response received and before return it
  // we can provide some manipulations, or so.
  //

  console.log('[step-5] exampleData return data:', data);
  return data;
};


const Example = () => {
  console.log('[step-1] Example: initialize exampleData()');
  const data = exampleData();

  console.log('[latest step] Example: data property: ', data);
  const text = data && data.id && Object.values(data).join(' : ')

  return React.createElement('div', null, text);
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Example), domContainer);
```

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why didn't you use `exampleData` the same way you did in `useApiHook`? You probably could create all that in a custom hook

Comment: @ViniciusKatata actually yes, I can use `exampleData` as hook `useExampleData`. But I just curious about the approach and what is the best one to use.